# what is the difference between reverse, reverse_lazy, resolve and redirect? [Django]

Tags: django

what is the difference between those next terms:
reverse, reverse_lazy, resolve and redirect
I think when I have to use return then I have to use redirect but if this is true?; why I can't use reverse instead of redirect?
also, when I should use these methods?

Answer (score 4):

**resolve()** function can be used for resolving URL paths to the corresponding view functions.

**reverse()** function: It’s similar to the `url` template tag which use to convert namespaced url to real url pattern.

For example:

```
def test_list_reverse():
    """cheeses:list should reverse to /cheeses/."""
    assert reverse('cheeses:list') == '/cheeses/'

def test_list_resolve():
    """/cheeses/ should resolve to cheeses:list."""
    assert resolve('/cheeses/').view_name == 'cheeses:list'
```

• Reversing the view name should give us the absolute URL.
• Resolving the absolute URL should give us the view name.

The example in resolve gives a good idea of what's it for. Generally I've only used reverse as I need the url. I haven't used it but resolve gives you the view that the reverse url points to

For more details read [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/)

Comment: You forgot to talk about `reverse_lazy()`.