# What's the difference between Reverse vs. Redirect in Django?

Tags: django

I am doing a django project, and is very confused about reverse, reverse_lazy and redirect.

Can redirect function redirect with parameters? Or should I change method to reverse whenever I want to post parameters?

Comment: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/difference-between/reverse-redirect.html

Comment: Here's a detailed answer from a question that looks similar.
[Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61858520/12246264)

Answer (score 4):

> Can redirect function redirect with parameters?

**Yes**. Imagine that you have a url pattern with:

```
 path('foo/<str:bar>/<id:pk>/', name='some_path')
```

you can redirect to that path with:

```
    return redirect('some_path', bar='value-for-bar', pk=1425)
```

> is very confused about reverse, reverse_lazy and redirect.

`reverse` and `reverse_lazy` determine the *path* for a given view name. That path is a *string*, not a HTTP response, you can not return such string as a result for a view.

The [**`redirect(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) will call [**`reverse(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) internally and wrap the result in a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) or [**`HttpResponsePermanentRedirect`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect).

It thus combines two layers with each other: the urls layer to calculate the path, and the view layer to construct a HTTP response, that is why it is defined in the [**`django.shortcuts`** module [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts).